# Unity "Combines" Joystick inputs, But only when both controllers have the same name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem i'm having is a bit difficult to explain, so I apologize if i go into to much detail here.

I've created a system in my game that uses the Unity Input manager to assign controls to each player, based on how many controllers are plugged in. This system has worked perfectly for months now, tested with up to 4 controllers at a time, with no problems.

Today, I plugged in 2 Xbox One controllers and tried to play the latest build of my game. Which, to be clear, has worked in the past, with this exact same setup.

When trying to move Joystick 1,  the input manager does not detect any input. But, if you slightly move any of the axis on Joystick 2, it begins to "Combine" the inputs of both controls, so you have to use both joysticks to make the Input Manager see the input, and even then it does not work quite properly, the result lags behind the input quite significantly.

I have also discovered that this happens EXCLUSIVELY when the game is started. If I wait until the game has loaded, and then plug the controllers in, unity reads them perfectly fine.

It works in a similar manner before the game is built, in the Unity Editor. If i have both controllers plugged in when the editor loads, I have the exact same issue. But if I plug them in after the editor is up, but before I've hit "Play", they function perfectly fine.

Lastly, It only happens if the controllers have the same name, as far as i can tell. I plugged in a PS3 controller and one of the Xbox one controllers before the game was oppened, and both the PS3 and Xbox one controllers functioned exactly as they were supposed to.

I've created a new scene, with the only code being what is listed here, Which i have been using to test this issue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AxisTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Renderer joystick1axis1P;
    public Renderer joystick1axis1N;
    public Renderer joystick1axis2P;
    public Renderer joystick1axis2N;
    public Renderer joystick2axis1P;
    public Renderer joystick2axis1N;
    public Renderer joystick2axis2P;
    public Renderer joystick2axis2N;

    public Material onMaterial;
    public Material offMaterial;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick1Axis1") > 0)
        joystick1axis1P.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick1axis1P.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick1Axis1") < 0)
        joystick1axis1N.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick1axis1N.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick1Axis2") > 0)
        joystick1axis2P.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick1axis2P.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick1Axis2") < 0)
        joystick1axis2N.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick1axis2N.material = offMaterial;

    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick2Axis1") > 0)
        joystick2axis1P.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick2axis1P.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick2Axis1") < 0)
        joystick2axis1N.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick2axis1N.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick2Axis2") > 0)
        joystick2axis2P.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick2axis2P.material = offMaterial;
    if (Input.GetAxis("Joystick2Axis2") < 0)
        joystick2axis2N.material = onMaterial;
    else
        joystick2axis2N.material = offMaterial;
}
}
```

My Input Manager, which i have not changed,[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEIMT.jpg), and 
the other inputs are set up following the same pattern.

Both Unity and Windows are updated fully, although I have not gotten the opportunity to test this on another computer.

I believe that covers everything. So is there some setting in unity or windows that i may have accidentally turned on? Does it have to do with WHEN unity detects controllers in its start up process?

Please help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I seem to be having something similar with Unity 2018.4.14f1.  I have two Logitech F310.  If I start unity with them plugged in, the axis inputs (I have not tried buttons) only seem to be non-zero if I move the joysticks on the controllers simultaneously.  If I wait to plug them in after unity is started, they appear to work ok.

Comment: I actually Did not manage to "Fix" this issue, It just stopped happening after updating. But it definitely didn't fix until months after I asked this question. I guess it was just something weird with unity.

Comment: Which version was it fixed in?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. All i know is between when I posted this and now, one of the updates got rid of the problem.